# function called in function throwing undefined function error

Tags: php, function, class, oop, undefined

using the object-oriented approach, i'm trying to call a public function in a function in the same class, but it throws an error: `Call to undefined function h()`

php:

```
class Name {
    . .. .
    public function h($s) 
    {
    echo htmlspecialchars($s, ENT_QUOTES);
     }

    public function formatQuotes($row)
    {

    return "<p id=\"ab_quotes\">" . h($row['cQuotes']) . "</p>"
    . "<p id=\"ab_author\">" . h($row['vAuthor']) . "</p>";             
    }

}
```

what am i missing here?

Comment: Tip: Use `'` instead of `"`. So you don't need to escape anything ;)

Comment: FYI, you do not need to include [keywords] in the question title.  That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call methods in the same class using `$this->`. It isn't implicit like it is in languages such as C++

So, to call h

```
$this->h($row['cQuotes']);
```

Answer (score 3):

**You must use this to access any non static member of a class from inside it**

```
{
    return "<p id=\"ab_quotes\">" . $this->h($row['cQuotes']) . 
           "</p>". "<p id=\"ab_author\">" . $this->h($row['vAuthor']) . 
           "</p>";             
}
```

Comment: +1 for answering 1st (i was just about to answer similarly). tho' you gorra learn to format your code (4 spaces should do the trick) :)

Comment: its just copied from @fusions :(

Comment: using this code, all my formatting disappeared. do you know why?